# Pause SVG animation after 1 full rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, svg

There is a super cool svg animation here - http://codepen.io/aptary/pen/fcKyI

It loops indefinitely though.

Is there a way to stop this svg animation after one full rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's cool!

Try editing the CSS to change `animation-iteration-count` from `infinite` to `1`